# Making Javascript getSeconds more accurate or use different function

Tags: javascript

I am using the following to calculate time elapsed:

```
    var start = new Date();
    var end;
    var total;
    end = new Date();
    total = end.getSeconds() - start.getSeconds();
```

Now this will produce "total" as for example, 8, 4, 14. How can I modify this to give me 4.23, 8.56, 14.12? Do I need to pass something into getSeconds or use a different function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getTime()` instead of `getSeconds()`, it will return the time in milliseconds.

Additionally, your method will break if `end` is more than one minute ahead of `start`. If you record `start` at, say, 12:30:52 and `end` at 12:31:01 then you would expect `total` to be 9, but with your code it will be -51.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the warning, do you know what my alternative is?

Comment: My answer, using getTime() because it will return the "unix timestamp" in milliseconds.